# undefined variable when i called it on a header view in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

My route is:

```php
Route::get('header','HomeController@header')->name('header');
```

My functionality is:

```php
public function header()
{
    $header=ParentCategory::latest()->get();
    return view('includes.header',compact('header'));
}
```

My view foreach loop is here:

```php
@foreach($header as $pc)
    <li class=" aligned-left parent dropdown " >
    <a href="index7fa3.html?route=product/category&amp;path=18"
        class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="menu-title">{{$pc->name}}</span><b class="caret"></b></a>      
@endforeach
```

I don't want to write their route which name is header, mention in browser I want to work my foreach loop without route name, header.

Comment: I've edited you post so it is formatted better.  Please take note of how to use the code blocks.  I still don't completely understand what you are asking though so if the answer below isn't what you are looking for, please try to explain your question more.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for your variable first before looping through it:

```
 @if($header)
   @foreach($header as $pc)   
        <li class=" aligned-left parent dropdown " >
           <a href="index7fa3.html?route=product/category&amp;path=18"
    class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span class="menu-title">{{$pc->name}}</span><b class="caret"></b>
           </a>   
         </li>   
   @endforeach 
 @endif
```

Comment: its working but this  header foreach loop is in my nav bar and call it on everypage, i don't write the route which name is header is in the browser again and again,what can i do,suggest something.

Comment: You can replace it with a forward slash `Route::get('/','HomeController@header')->name('header');`

Comment: So you can put that code  in the view that corresponds to the home route - i mean the the route with a forward slash

Comment: if i write this code in home route so its just work for home page but i want to use this nav-bar header on every page

Comment: then you can extract this code and and put it as a main layout for your entire app.

Comment: i made a base controller and here i write a function
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $parentCategories = ParentCategory::all();
        View::share('parentCategories',$parentCategories);
//        return view('public-pages.home.index',compact('homeProducts','homeLectures','viewComment','gameSoftware','parentCategories'));

    }
}
and after it i extend other controllers from this base controller,how to fetch data from this base controller in my view(header.blade) file